# d3.js - set links size to a force layout

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

Based on the "Molecule" example of Michael Bostock, available at this url : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3037015.

I'm trying to set the size of my links with several values. For that, I disabled the "gravity", put an important negative value in "charge" and fixed the first node to the center of my window.

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(-800)
    .friction(0.45)
    .linkStrength(1)
    .gravity(0)
    .linkDistance(function(d) { 
        return radius(d.target.size * 10);
     });
```

My problem is ([image: as you can see on the image below]) sometimes the size of the links are differents, especially for links defined with a little value.

Does somebody know one good solution for my problem?

You can see my code here : http://jsfiddle.net/awPn3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a characteristic of the force layout that the length of the links is variable -- the point is that the nodes are laid out automatically and you don't have to worry about it. You could implement checks that make sure that the distances are always what you want them to be, but this would be quite difficult.

The `linkDistance` function that you're using already is the only direct way to (weakly) enforce such a constraint. If that's not enough, there's no easy way of mitigating it. Your only option would be to implement checks like I've mentioned above at each tick of the simulation.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me an example?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such example. This would be quite complex to implement and I don't think anybody has ever done it.

Comment: Ok thanks. What do you think about to implement a repulsive force for each nodes?

Comment: That won't ensure that all the distances are as you want them to be either. You'll have to check that manually.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would already help a bit when you modify the function that you use, to also account for the size of both ends' objects. Let the solution be optimized towards setting the 'visible' distance between the two objects: e.g. along the lines of (d.source.size+d.target.size) + desired_distance